# VB.net error (Load Report Failed) When RPT file being open in Crystal Reports designer

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I use VB.net 2010 and Crystal Report XI.
I want to load the report in a report viewer, but when i open the rpt file in crystal reports designer, the report viewer in vb.net give error : load report failed.

But when i close the crystal report software or just close the rpt file from crystal reports software, then the report viewer can run just fine.
Do i really have to close crystal reports every time i want to open the rpt file from report viewer in vb.net.?

In case of being needed, this is my code:

```
Dim Report As New ReportDocument
    Dim Report1 As New ReportDocument
    Dim li As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim tbs As Tables
    Dim tb As Table
    Try
        Report.Load(reportLocation & filename)

        li.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = dbname
        li.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userid
        li.ConnectionInfo.Password = password
        li.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = servername

        tbs = Report.Database.Tables
        For Each tb In Report.Database.Tables
            tb.ApplyLogOnInfo(li)
        Next

        Report.RecordSelectionFormula += IIf(Report.RecordSelectionFormula <> "", " and ", "") & formula
        Report.Refresh()
        Report.SetParameterValue(0, param(0))
        Report.SetParameterValue(1, param(1))
        Report.SetParameterValue(2, param(2))
        If param(3) <> "" Then Report.SetParameterValue(3, param(3))

        crV.ReportSource = Report
        crV.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

In case of being asked, I use windows 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to move back to Windows 7, and in win 7 i didn't get any of these problem.
Maybe its more like compatibility issue or something.
So i think, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your report path; this is your problem. The System cannot find that the report exists.

This one specifically:

```
<pre>
    Report.Load(reportLocation & filename)



    check it using string variable like this;
     string getpath = reportLocation & filename;

    just check it if its location is the same by checking getpath variable



   secondly: crystal report need to login to your working database thats why it says load report failed.




  if this one working well then you dont have any problem regarding the     crystal report path:

     tbs = Report.Database.Tables
    For Each tb In Report.Database.Tables
        tb.ApplyLogOnInfo(li)
    Next

</pre>
```

Comment: i've double check, triple check and more than multiple check, the report is exist in that path.

Comment: i'm sure that declaration method is not for vb.net because it give error, but i have check another way using immediate, and i'm sure the result is exactly the same as where the report file placed.

Answer (score 0):

go to the properties of the crystal report and under to copy to output directory select copy always

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).